# How to write a nested switch case in python?

Tags: python-3.x, switch-statement

Is that even possible?

What I know so far:

Python hasn't switch case but they have something called dictionary mapping.

```
def fun1():print("fun1")
def fun2():print("fun2")
def fun3():print("fun3")

def WannaBeSwitch(arg):
    switch = {
        0: fun1,
        1: fun2,
        2: fun3
    }
    return switch.get(arg, "blabla")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    argument = 1
    call_func = WannaBeSwitch(argument)
    call_func()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the python project in which I needed to implement nested switch.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58973050/10062908) helped me a lot.
Here is working example based on that answer. The example is how I implemented it in my project. You can make changes to fit it with your needs.

```
def fun1_1():print("fun1_1")
def fun1_2():print("fun1_2")
def fun1_3():print("fun1_3")

def fun1(sub_case):
    sub_switch = {
        1: fun1_1,
        2: fun1_2,
        3: fun1_3
    }
    sub_switch.get(sub_case, default_case)()
    return

def fun2_1():print("fun2_1")
def fun2_2():print("fun2_2")
def fun2_3():print("fun2_3")

def fun2(sub_case):
    sub_switch = {
        1: fun2_1,
        2: fun2_2,
        3: fun2_3
    }
    sub_switch.get(sub_case, default_case)()
    return

def fun3_1():print("fun3_1")
def fun3_2():print("fun3_2")
def fun3_3():print("fun3_3")

def fun3(sub_case):
    sub_switch = {
        1: fun3_1,
        2: fun3_2,
        3: fun3_3
    }
    sub_switch.get(sub_case, default_case)()
    return

def default_case(): print("Unsupported case!")

main_switch = {
    1: fun1,
    2: fun2,
    3: fun3
}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_case = 2
    sub_case = 3
    main_switch.get(main_case)(sub_case)
```